# Please help me solve for the angle.

Tags: geometry

Steps that I had done to try to solve this problem:

1. Calculated the third angle for the bigger triangle.
2. The two angles were identical so, I considered the triangle to be isosceles. (Angle= 80 degrees)
3. I drew a line parallel to the bottom side of the bigger triangle.
4. Then a new triangle was formed which was similar to the bigger triangle.
   I got stuck after that as the ratio of sides did not lead me anywhere.
   [image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vhklRWogzo&t=190s

Comment: Many variations of angle chasing in $80$-$80$-$20$ triangle: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/IndexToClassical.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Just draw an equilateral triangle with its side length equal to the base of the main triangle.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution.